# Smooth UISearchController navigation bar transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a navigation controller with a root view controller that sets its titeView to a UISearchBar. Upon submitting their query, I push on another view controller which also has a UISearchBar populated with their query. If possible, I would like to keep this search bar in place and just transition the view controller below it. Is this possible with a navigation controller? Or do I need to make a custom container view controller.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a new custom view & do transition animation to the custom view upon submitting the query. This way will keep `UISearchBar` stay in place.